# How long does it take for previous versions of an app to be updated to the newly released version rolled out to the goolge play store?

Tags: google-play

I rolled out a  new version of my app. I wonder how long would it take to get that version propagated to all current users. Is that done automatically?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not Google Play Store support. We have no access to your app or account at the Play Store. This question is not programming related. Contact Google directly for questions relating to your app and their Play Store. For more information, see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/62576)

Answer (score 0):

It is done automatically, but is under the control of each user. By default, all users have automatic updates turned on. This will update apps when users are on Wi-Fi and plugged into power. Each device checks roughly once per day. However, there will always be some users who don't get updates:

- some users have automatic updates turned off and choose not to update
- some users never have Wi-Fi and Power, and choose not to update manually
- some users don't have enough free disk space to update.

So it usually doesn't take that long to get to most users (within a few days), but the final tail of users can take much longer.